# Error while setting Gradient color in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am totally new android and I don't know whats wrong with my code.

I see red exclamation mark before this line `android:background="@drawable/myBtnWithColor"`

check the image below

[image]

Here is my myBtnWithColor.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
    <!--  Gradient Bg for listrow -->
   <gradient
      android:startColor="#f1f1f2"
      android:centerColor="#e7e7e8"
      android:endColor="#cfcfcf"
      android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename your file to mybtnwithcolor. Don't use upper-case letters in xml file names.